# How to insert a batch of records into Redis

Tags: stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

In a twitter-like application, one of the things they do is when someone posts a tweet, they iterate over all followers and create a copy of the tweet in their timeline. I need something similar. What is the best way to insert a tweet ID into say 10/100/1000 followers assuming I have a list of follower IDs.

I am doing it within Azure WebJobs using Azure Redis. Each webjob is automatically created for every tweet received in the queue. So I may have around 16 simultaneous jobs running at the same time where each one goes through followers and inserts tweets.I'm thinking if 99% of inserts happen, they should not stop because one or a few have failed. I need to continue but log it.

**Question**: Should I do CreateBatch like below? If I need to retrieve latest tweets first in reverse chronological order is below fine? performant?

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
var batch = _cache.CreateBatch();
//loop start
tasks.Add(batch.ListRightPushAsync("follower_id", "tweet_id"));
//loop end
batch.Execute();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

a) But how do I catch if something fails? try catch?
b) how do I check in a batch for a total # in each list and pop one out if it reaches a certain #? I want to do a LeftPop if the list is > 800. Not sure how to do it all inside the batch.

Please point me to a sample or let me have a snippet here. Struggling to find a good way. Thank you so much.

**UPDATE**
Does this look right based on @marc's comments?

```
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        followers.ForEach(f =>
        {
            var key = f.FollowerId;
            var task = _cache.ListRightPushAsync(key, value);
            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.Result > 800) _cache.ListLeftPopAsync(key).Wait();
            });
            tasks.Add(task);
        });
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: I think you're thinking on this is backwards.  You wouldn't insert the tweet into each followers record, what if they stop following the user? You would have to delete all the tweets stored from that user.  Rather a user should make a tweet, and when a follower of that user visits the page it will get all of that users tweets

Comment: See http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html. You have to think of fast reads, as 99.9% of all traffic is reads so they optimize for reads. Regardless of that though, my questions deal with redis details. Looking to see how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. CreateBatch probably doesn't do what you think it does. What it does is *defer* a set of operations and ensure they get sent contiguously relative to a single connection - there are some occasions this is useful, but not *all* that common - I'd probably just send them individually if it was me. There *is* also CreateTransaction (MULTI/EXEC), but I don't think that would be a good choice here.
2. That depends on whether you care about the data you're popping. If not: I'd send a LTRIM, [L|R]PUSH pair - to trim the list to (max-1) before adding. Another option would be Lua, but it seems overkill. If you care about the old data, you'll need to do a range query too.

Comment: 1) Can you elaborate on what you mean by contiguously? They are sent next to each other but not necessarily as one call to Redis? If I have a 1000 followers, make a call to Redis 1000 times? Looking for best performance. 2)I don't care about data popped. can you elaborate on how to do that in StackExchange.Redis? Just want to store latest 800. Want 801st (oldest) removed

Comment: @tim the "next to each other ties into the multiplexed multi-threaded nature of SE.Redis: it means that no other threads *on that multiplexer* will get commands in the middle - but that doesn't mean they will be contiguous at the server - the server can interleave operations from any connection. Pipelining 1000 commands is perfectly reasonable: you aren't paying for latency, since they all get sent " almost immediately" - the almost here meaning: it tries to minimise packet fragmentation too - all automatically.

Comment: @tim so basically: you could just use _cache.WhateverAsync and it would work just about the same, for your scenario. Re the list trimming: see ListTrimAsync and the documentation for LTRIM - sorry, I incorrectly said *REM earlier: I meant LTRIM - http://redis.io/commands/ltrim

Comment: @tim the key point about ltrim: you don't need to know the current length. Say the max you want is 800: you just say "trim to 799, add 1"; now regardless of how many were there before, you have *no more than* 800

Comment: sorry if too many questions but a) can you put a snippet on how to do pipelining in my example? b)also, in my case since I do RPUSH, won't LPOP be better to remove oldest? or are you saying have a separate job that calls LTRIM on a timer of whatever accumulated past 800 in my case?

Comment: I updated with latest code snippet in the question. How would you do it using pipelining?

Comment: @Tim on the edit: don't use continuewith there; commands are delivered in order: just send a trim and a push - no need to do anything complex like continuewith - again, the point of trim (to desired length minus one) being; you *don't need to know the current length*

Comment: @Tim re the distinction of left/right: please see what ltrim says about negative numbers. You can get it to trim *the other way*

Comment: @Tim re pipelining: you already are - there are two ways of pipelining in SE.Redis: 1) use the *Async API, or 2) use the non-*Async (sync) API, but pass CommandFlags.FireAndForget. With either of these you can send a mass of outbound messages without paying latency

Comment: @Tim hmmm; I've been trying to find the magic voodoo for ltrim to work this way, but it is defeating me - I might just be having a stupid moment; you *might* want to ask on the redisdb google-group to see if there's a good way to rpush and ltrim together (lpush and ltrim are trivial); worst case, you could use Lua (ScriptEvaluate) - that would IMO be preferable to your continue-with