# .NET StackExchangeRedis and order of execution with Batch not guaranteed?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, async-await, stackexchange.redis

I am reviewing the following code which is trying to:

- add an key/value to a Redis db.
- set an expiry on that new redis key.

i.e.

```
{
    var batch = database.CreateBatch();

    var tasks = new Task[]
    {
        batch.SetAddAsync(key, value, flags),
        batch.KeyExpireAsync(key, expiry, flags)
    };

    batch.Execute();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
}
```

do this all in a single redis `Batch`.

My impression is that you cannot assume order, when it comes to batching, let alone multiple tasks in `async/await`.

As such, the following order might occur:

- `KeyExpiresAsync` <-- key doesn't exist yet.
- `SetAddAsync` <-- key doesn't exist. key is created. Then members added to key.

I hope and don't want the order to be guaranteed, meaning .. it's try to parallel this as fast as it could.

So - is my understanding correct or misplaced?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/30083293/34092 help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is guaranteed and the operations will not occur in parallel.

Paraphrasing one of the authors (@Mark-Gravell):

What a batch does is defer a set of operations and ensure they get sent next to each other contiguously to a single connection, so no other threads on that multiplexer will get commands in the middle.

## Update

@mjwills already mentioned an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30083293/34092). Also [this unit test](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/MigratedBookSleeveTestSuite/Batches.cs#L32) assumes so. Also you can verify that on the [RedisBridge.cs](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisBatch.cs#L15) code. Even in a cluster, since you are issuing both commands to the same key, both will go to the same node, and they are internally pushed to/pulled from a [Queue](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/MessageQueue.cs#L6).

Comment: Reference to the original quote/docs, please? (not trolling, just honestly curious, etc).

Comment: Just updated the answer. Unfortunately there is no good documentation on SE.Redis.